# Not able to Find Locate the Element through xpath using Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, ide

Xpath i am getting is - id('submitButtonWrapper')/x:input for 'Login button'on application but not able to target the field.

URL of the application - https://authentication.liveperson.net/

Answer (score 1):

Try with the Following Xpath Expression:

```
Driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='submitButtonWrapper']/input")).click();
```

Comment: Getting Error

[error] Element Driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='submitButtonWrapper']/input")).click(); not found
[info] Test case failed

Answer (score 0):

You can find this by using the Record button in Selenium IDE.
In case you prefer to do it manually, here is what you should enter:

```
Command: Click
Target: name=loginButton
Value:
```

Comment: I tried it too and it worked. If I understand correctly, you want to click on the orange 'Sign in' button right ?

Comment: yes correct orange button.Test case is passed but page not navigating to the next page.

Comment: well, that seems outside the scope of your original question. you asked how to click the button. I have no login credentials to that website so I can't help you further with your problem that the page doesn't navigate to the next page.

Comment: I cant understand the limitation but when scripts runs with wrong credential its should give error for 'Wrong password'. So could you please confirm are you getting any such error. Please attached the Screen shot if you getting after clicking on 'Sign In' with wrong ID and password.

Comment: I can't help you because I don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: Please follow below steps . Steps.
1. Enter the  Account Number (11692)
2. Enter the UserID (43968392)
3. Enter the Password Welcome10
4. Click on Sign In
Expected - Once you click on Sign In user should get ‘Login Failed’ message.

Query- I am not getting this ‘Login failed’ error message through below command.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution of your problem, It will work with `clickAt` command. So in this way change your code -

```
Command: clickAt
Target: name=loginButton
Value:
```

the command specification says -

> clickAt(locator, coordString)
>       Arguments:
>
> 1. locator - an element locator
> 2. coordString - specifies the x,y position (i.e. - 10,20) of the mouse event relative to the element returned by the locator.
>
>    Clicks on a link, button, checkbox or radio button. If the click action causes a new page to load (like a link usually does), call
>      waitForPageToLoad.

I'm not much clear with this command but i was able to selecting items from **chozen** dropdowns only with `clickAt` but not with `click` command